# How to apply different directory and file permissions recursively by one command

Tags: permissions, file-permissions, chmod

Let's assume that I have this folder structure:

```
|-Home    
 |-Subdir
  |-Subsubdir
 |-Subdir
```

Each directory includes a bunch of files.

Now I want to apply the following permissions:

- All directories - 750
- All files in these directories - 644

Is it possible to do it in one go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could do it in 2 passes

```
find /path/to/Home -type d -exec chmod 750 {} \+
find /path/to/Home -type f -exec chmod 744 {} \+
```

Why do you need to do it in 'one go' ?

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Of course it does not have to be in "one go" :). Thank you.